# Need a way to refresh automatically update HTML if a text file changes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a non intrusive pop up that refreshes it's displayed text on the fly if the content in a local txt file has been changed. Not sure of the best method to go about this. Using html and js for this.

The popup reads from a txt file, pops up on screen for a few seconds then pops back down, but how could I read the file and change what is displayed automatically?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read from local files unless the user drags them into your page, or loads them with a file input.  Once that is done, a lock is placed on the file so that the file cannot be modified.

Basically, you can't do what you want to do.